# How to select records form a table with current date and custom time range?

Tags: mysql

I am having a table with seperate `date and time` column. I need to select all data from my table checking two condition

**1.records with current date(todays date).**

**2.records with custom time range.**

This is my table structure

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|    id      |   item     |    description      |    bill_date      |       bill_time    |
+------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|    1       |    x       |    test             |   2016-04-15      |     12:05:00       |
+------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|    2       |    y       |    test1            |   2016-04-15      |     01:10:44       |
+------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|    3       |    z       |    test2            |   2016-04-16      |     05:10:10       |
+------------+------------+---------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

I could select time range using this mysql query

```
SELECT * FROM `bill_item` WHERE `bill_time` BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '06:00:00'
```

this returns `2,3 record` now I **need to check if the record is todays record**. How to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You need something like `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE()`.

Comment: Yes I just do not know to write a subquery from result of time range @PaulSpiegel

Comment: You don't need a subquery. There can be more than one condition in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE (bill_time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '06:00:00') AND bill_date = CURRENT_DATE()`

Comment: can you please make a answer to this question@PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have multiple conditions in the `WHERE` clause. You can use `CURRENT_DATE()` or `NOW()` to get only todays entries.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bill_item` 
WHERE (bill_time BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '06:00:00') 
  AND bill_date = CURRENT_DATE()
```

See the official documentation for more [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)